# Proving $\int \delta'(x-x')f(x') \, dx'=\frac{df}{dx}$ by starting from finite dimensional to infinite dimensional

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, dirac-delta

We are given an assignment problem with goes like  this:

> Consider a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Divide $[0,1]$ into $N$ bins: $\left[0,\frac{1}{N}\right),\left[\frac{1}{N},\frac{2}{N} \right), \ldots , \left[1-\frac{1}{N},1\right)$ and approximate $f$ by its values $\{f_n\}$ at the centre of the $n^\text{th}$ bin.

- Write down the $N\times N$ matrix such that  $D$ such that $$D\begin{bmatrix}
  f_1 \\
  \vdots\\
  f_N
  \end{bmatrix}$$
  gives an approximation to $df/dx$.
- Now  go back to the continuum description. Show that  as $N\rightarrow \infty$ the operator $D$ becomes an operator $\mathcal{D}$ with the property
  $$\int \mathcal{D}(x-x')f(x') \, dx'=\frac{df}{dx}$$
- Express $\mathcal{D}(x-x')$  in terms of the Dirac Delta function.

---

What I have done so far,

[image]

The derivative defined as
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
In this case,
$$\left.\frac{df}{dx}\right|_{i^\text{th} \text{bin}}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_{i+1}-f_i}{1/N}=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}N(f_{i+1}-f_i)$$
So I can write the derivative operator as matrix like
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 0& \ddots \\
0 & -1 & 1 & \ddots \\
\ddots&0&-1&\ddots 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know, How to start the second part? I don't understand, How do $D$ go to  $\mathcal{D}(x-x')$?

I tried going backward that is
$$\int \mathcal{D}(x-x')f(x') \, dx'=\frac{df}{dx}\rightarrow \sum_i D(x-x_i) f(x_i) \, \Delta x=\frac{df}{dx}$$
I don't know what  to do know? Please help me with this.

Comment: Your title confuses $D$ with $\delta.$ They are not the same thing.

Comment: In particular, the thing you state you want to prove in the title is not true.

Comment: I got that , it was a typo.

Comment: The question is then, what is meant by $\delta’,$ given that even $\delta$ is not, technically, a function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Let's just not consider a title for a second and  talk what has been asked in the problem and what I should next.